# I want to write the following equation in multiple lines in two column paper?

Tags: equations

```
 the case of multiple resources the total time of activity \emph{"i"} with respect to the effect of personality of resources will be calculated as follows;
\begin{equation}
    TotalTime of a\textsubscript{i}= d\textsubscript{ai}Epr\textsubscript{i}   \hspace{1cm} and \hspace{.5cm}  where \hspace{.5cm} d\textsubscript{ai}Epr\textsubscript{i}= Maxd\textsubscript{ai}Epr\textsubscript{i}
\end{equation}
Where the total time of activity \emph{"a\textsubscript{i}"} will be equal to the the duration of resource \emph{"r\textsubscript{i }"} whose effect of personality and skill is equal to maximum duration of activity \emph{"a\textsubscript{i}"}.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't clearly see what you want to obtain as an equation. It's almost entirely a plain text.

Comment: The term `d\textsubscript{ai} Epr\textsubscript{i} = Max d\textsubscript{ai} Epr\textsubscript{i}` verges on being tautological. Can you verify that this is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your code outputs

[image]

I'm sorry in advance, but it looks *terrible*.

Why don't use math mode for math mode and text mode for text mode?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The case of multiple resources the total time of activity $i$ with respect to the effect of personality of resources will be calculated as follows
\begin{equation}
    \text{Total time of }a_i=d_{a_i}Epr_i \label{eq:totaltime}
\end{equation}
where
\[d_{a_i}Epr_i=\max d_{a_i}Epr_i\]
The total time of activity $a_i$ will be equal to the the duration of resource $r_i$ whose effect of personality and skill is equal to maximum duration of activity $a_i$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Two columns:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The case of multiple resources the total time of activity $i$ with respect to the effect of personality of resources will be calculated as follows
\begin{equation}
    \text{Total time of }a_i=d_{a_i}Epr_i \label{eq:totaltime}
\end{equation}
where
\[d_{a_i}Epr_i=\max d_{a_i}Epr_i\]
The total time of activity $a_i$ will be equal to the the duration of resource $r_i$ whose effect of personality and skill is equal to maximum duration of activity $a_i$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
The case of multiple resources the total time of activity $i$ with respect to the effect of personality of resources will be calculated as follows
\begin{equation}
    \text{Total time of }a_i=d_{a_i}Epr_i \label{eq:totaltime}
\end{equation}
where
\[d_{a_i}Epr_i=\max d_{a_i}Epr_i\]
The total time of activity $a_i$ will be equal to the the duration of resource $r_i$ whose effect of personality and skill is equal to maximum duration of activity $a_i$.
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]